# Parse API Result That Returns an Array and String

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have some data being returned from an API that is in the following format:

```
string(15) "hello@yahoo.com"
bool(true)
string(7) "generic"
array(5) {
  ["server"]=>
  string(19) "imap.mail.yahoo.com"
  ["username"]=>
  string(15) "hello@yahoo.com"
  ["port"]=>
  int(993)
  ["use_ssl"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["oauth"]=>
  bool(false)
}
array(0) {
}
```

When I am trying to parse this with a `foreach` loop, it is unsuccessful. I am assuming this is due to the `string(15)`, `bool(true)`, and `string(7)` pieces of data located above the actual array.

Here is my `foreach` loop:

```
$results = array();
foreach ($Request->getResults() as $imapSettings) {
    $results['server'] = $imapSettings['server'];
    $results['username'] = $imapSettings['username'];
    $results['port'] = $imapSettings['port'];
    $results['use_ssl'] = $imapSettings['use_ssl'];
    $results['oauth'] = $imapSettings['oauth'];
}
```

When I run the code above, I get the following error: `Warning: Illegal string offset 'server' in`. And I believe this error is usually a sign that something is not an array.

So my question is how do I go about parsing this piece of data?

UPDATE:

Here is was `var_dump($Request->getResults());` returns:

```
array(5) {
  ["email"]=>
  string(15) "hello@yahoo.com"
  ["found"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["type"]=>
  string(7) "generic"
  ["imap"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["server"]=>
    string(19) "imap.mail.yahoo.com"
    ["username"]=>
    string(15) "hello@yahoo.com"
    ["port"]=>
    int(993)
    ["use_ssl"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["oauth"]=>
    bool(false)
  }
  ["documentation"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the output for `gettype($imapSettings)`...???

Comment: It looks like you have multiple pieces of data there. A string followed by a boolean, followed by a string, followed by an array, followed by an empty array.

Comment: @tramp When I run `gettype($imapSettings)` this is the output `stringbooleanstringarrayarray`.

Comment: @jd182 Yep, is there anyway to parse that?

Comment: Strange... If I follow the order your username is boolean...?? The error message would have also mentioned the line no. too...?? Which line is it here...??

Comment: What does `$Request->getResults()` actually return? Can you paste the results of var_dump($Request->getResults()); please?

Comment: @jd182 I have updated my original posting with the results of `var_dump($Request->getResults());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to do:

```
$response = $Request->getResults();

$results['server']   = $response['imap']['server'];
$results['username'] = $response['imap']['username'];
$results['port']     = $response['imap']['port'];
$results['use_ssl']  = $response['imap']['use_ssl'];
$results['oauth']    = $response['imap']['oauth'];
```

You don't need to loop through the result - you can just pull out the information you need from the 'imap' array contained in the result.

Also you can do this more succinctly like this which will yield the same results:

```
$results = $response['imap'];
```

Comment: This almost works! But there seems to be duplicate data being added to the array. Here is a link to the data being dumped: http://pastebin.com/EnQ4dHPe

Comment: Yeah sorry - I updated my answer so that the $result uses a different variable name to the response.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured out what I did wrong. Your solution worked perfectly for me! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

foreach is only applicable for array, so you should escape the other types :

```
$results = array();
foreach ($Request->getResults() as $imapSettings) {
    if (!is_array($imapSettings)) {
        // you can do other stuff for other type
        continue;
    }
    $results['server'] = $imapSettings['server'];
    $results['username'] = $imapSettings['username'];
    $results['port'] = $imapSettings['port'];
    $results['use_ssl'] = $imapSettings['use_ssl'];
    $results['oauth'] = $imapSettings['oauth'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. This gets rid of the error message I was receiving, however, it does not assign the values to my `$results` array. Only `$results['server']` receives a value. The rest of the `$results` values are just `NULL`. Anyway to fix this?